# Partially Observable Markov Decision Process Optimal Value function

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, hidden-markov-models, reinforcement-learning, markov

I understood how belief states are updated in POMDP. But in Policy and Value function section, in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process I could not figure out how to calculate value of V*(T(b,a,o)) for finding optimal value function V*(b). I have read a lot of resources on the internet but none explain how to calculate this clearly. Can some one provide me with a mathematically solved example with all the calculations or provide me with a mathematically clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this tutorial on POMDPs:

http://cs.brown.edu/research/ai/pomdp/tutorial/index.html

It includes a section about *Value Iteration*, which can be used to find an optimal policy/value function.

Comment: The link proves good explanation of how value iteration works. But it does not give enough details on how the value is calculated. It assumes already a value is computed for a given action - observation and does not provide details on how we get that value in that belief state.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the same notation in this answer as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process#Policy_and_Value_Function).
First I repeat the Value Function as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process#Policy_and_Value_Function):

[image: value function]

*V<sup>*</sup>(b)* is the value function with the belief *b* as parameter. *b* contains the probability of all states *s*, which sum up to 1:

[image: sum_b]

*r(b,a)* is the reward for belief *b* and action *a* which has to be calculated using the belief over each state given the original reward function *R(s,a)*: the reward for being in state *s* and having done action *a*.

[image: reward def]

We can also write the function *O* in terms of states instead of belief *b*:

[image: o prob]

this is the probability of having observation *o* given a belief *b* and action *a*. Note that *O* and *T* are probability functions.

Finally the function *τ(b,a,o)* gives the new belief state *b'=τ(b,a,o)* given the previous belief *b*, action *a* and observation *o*. Per state we can calculate the new probability:

[image: belief update]

Now the new belief *b'* can be used to calculate iteratively: *V(τ(b,a,o))*.

The optimal value function can be approached by using for example [Value Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Value_iteration) which applies [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Then the function is iteratively updated until the difference is smaller then a small value ε.

There is a lot more information on POMDPs, for example:

- Sebastian Thrun, Wolfram Burgard, and Dieter Fox. 2005. Probabilistic Robotics (Intelligent Robotics and Autonomous Agents). The MIT Press.
- [A brief introduction to reinforcement learning](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/pomdp.html)
- [A POMDP Tutorial](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~jpineau/talks/jpineau-dagstuhl13.pdf)
- [Reinforcement Learning and Markov Decision Processes](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rjw/csg220/lectures/reinforcement.pdf)